# Generate Bones for Hair Cards

Tags: scripting, rigging, hair

How to generate an Armature that consists of bones for a hair cards geometry, using a script? This is what I want to make:

[image: Hair Cards Bones Example]

It's going to be tedious if we have to manually create bones for a dozen of hair cards, so I wonder if there is a way to automate the rigging process. Here is the file:

[Hair Cards Geometry](https://mega.nz/file/8qp0lTZC#LXjQUTH1MylwHmnlTQ8-Yx_j5W9UnGAySpZWtYoPIvM)

Comment: You can write a script that creates the bones. The task is a bit challenging because you need to define where the root of the card should be. For example, the HairNet addon requires a seam mark for this. I just wonder how many hair cards you have. Usually, there are a few hundred to cover the whole head. If each card has 3 or 5 bones you will end up with a thousand bones, won't you?

Comment: I tried to use ChatGPT to generate the script, but it always gives me scripts that produce errors